# Remove null values from stdout in ansible

Tags: null, ansible

Can someone let me know how to remove null values from stdout_lines.
*Output*

```
"stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Softwarecoder.exe",
        "",
        "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software\\cat8.5.exe",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ]
```

*Expected Output*

```
"stdout_lines": [
        "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Softwarecoder.exe",
        "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software\\cat8.5.exe"

    ]
```

I tried as below

```
path: "{{test.stdout_lines | rejectattr('') }}"
path: "{{test.stdout_lines | reject('')|list }}"
path: "{{test.stdout_lines | rejectattr('')|list }}"
```

But I Get error as below or no change in output:

```
"path": "<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7fb349f45cd0>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reject](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#reject) does the job

```yaml
    path: "{{ stdout_lines|reject('match', '^$')|list }}"
```

as well as [select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select)

```yaml
    path: "{{ stdout_lines|select('match', '.+')|list }}"
```